# HTTP Caching Server that supports POST

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, httpd, cache, varnish

I am hosting a REST service which is sending appropriate cache-control headers. I use Varnish as a caching server in front of my webserver. However, a limitation of varnish is that it doesn't support caching HTTP POST and HTTP PUT. Is there any alternate caching server that will be able to cache these requests?

I understand that caching POST is a bit tricky because you cannot just cache based on the url as a key like for GET; it needs to actually inspect the request body. In case of `multipart/form-data` requests, there should probably be a limit on the size of the request body for it to be cached  (so that big file uploads, etc won't be cached). Nevertheless I really want to be able to cache short HTTP POST, or at least the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of caching is to provide same responses to the same request without asking a back-end system. The problem with POST requests is, that you have to inspect the body to decide when two requests are the same. The best solution is to change from POST to GET.

If this is not applicable you can try [Nginx' proxy module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_key) with following setup (see the required limitation of the body size):

```
location @apache_backend {
    ...
    proxy_cache_methods   POST;
    proxy_cache_key       "$uri|$request_body";
    client_max_body_size  1k;
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the `client_max_body_size`. I thought that for requests > 1k it would bypass the proxy, but it will completely deny the request.

Comment: You know the behavior with using the POST's body for cache is more or less bound to a limit. It might be a little bigger than 1k but this is more or less right. So you have to decide whats more important, to cache POSTs or to have big POSTs.

Comment: What do you mean? It seems to work fine if I remove the client_max_body size. The cache db doesn't use the entire body as a key, it uses a md5 hashkey which is always 32 characters.

Comment: A, that's fine. I found this recommendation by Igor Sysoev.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question with [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx), but apparently you are not aware of the [`proxy_cache_methods` and `proxy_cache_key` directives](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_methods) which should allow you to proxy POST responses as well, provided your server makes use of cache control headers for POST responses.

The idea would be to include the `POST` method with proxy_cache_methods and find a suitable line for [proxy_cache_key](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_key). The default value of `$scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;` would not work well as you suspect, but you can choose from the large list of [Nginx variables](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables) to get something which would fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate a bit on how nginx deals with the concerns mentioned in the post?